# Filtering SQLite database by item "popularity"- Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am wondering how could I order items by popularity in my app's SQLite database.

The app connects to my online server and syncs information automatically via JSON. Items are usualy saved by the user on the phone, and added to a list, I thought I could send all the clicked item "IDs" back to the server where I could easily query and order them, but by what??

I mean how could I "measure" which item is most returned to my online database, and then generate a list ordered by popularity for the users?

Suggestions are welcomed.
Ved.

/////////
UPDATE

I have solved this issue using the following, maybe it could help others:

php script:

```
<?php

//connecting to database
include_once '../includes/psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

$table = palarm_entries;
$event_title = $_POST['event_title'];

$query =  "SELECT POPULAR FROM palarm_entries WHERE TITLE ='$event_title' ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$new_value = $row[POPULAR] + 1;

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET POPULAR = '$new_value' WHERE TITLE = '$event_title' ";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a field to the items table called something like counter. Then add 1 to it each time the item is selected. I would select the counter int of the item, add 1, then update.

Then do a

```
  SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY counter LIMIT 10;
```

This would return the top 10, just change the * to the info you need